# What does 'lretq' instruction do?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instructions, memory-segmentation

I saw 'lretq' instruction being used in a codebase, but it isn't listed in amd64 instruction manual. What does this instruction do?

Comment: It is at&t syntax for a far return, `RETF` in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @Jester Where can I find the list of all such at&t instructions?

Comment: Some are listed in the [gas manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html) `lretq` isn't, but `lcall` is mentioned.

Comment: There isn't a complete list.  You can always assemble it, then look up the opcode from the machine code yourself in http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html or other opcode map.  Or disassemble again with a different disassembler, or at least into GAS intel_syntax.